# Error: Package "ggplot2" could not be found, when loading the caret package

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-caret

When I install caret with.

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies=c("Depends", "Suggests"))
library(caret)
## Loading required package: lattice
## Loading required package: ggplot2
```

> Error in LoadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck=vI[[i]]):
>   there is no package called 'digest'
>   Error: package 'ggplot2' could not be loaded.

So I resolve the issue with the package digest by installing caret using this code and what do I get again:

```
install.packages("caret",  dep="TRUE")
library(caret)
## Loading required package: lattice
## Loading required package: ggplot2
```

> Error in LoadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck=vI[[i]]):
>   there is no package called 'gtable'
>   Error: package 'ggplot2' could not be loaded.

How do I install caret successfully without this kind of errors, especially the ggplot2 error!

my R Version is R 3.2.2

Comment: what happens if you try `install.packages("ggplot2")`?

Comment: `install.packages("caret",  dep="TRUE")` should be `install.packages("caret",  dep=TRUE)` (without quotes, so it's a boolean instead of a string)

Comment: Maybe just try running `update.packages()`. Sounds like you've gotten your package versions out-of-sync somehow.

Comment: Also, what are the results of `.libPaths()`?

Comment: @jeremycg I did that and it worked out fine but there was still some missing packages so it still couldn't load. Had to install them individually till ggplot could load in R

Comment: @CactusWoman Thanks for that, it did load most of the missing packages, not all though.

Comment: @MrFlick doubt that was the case then, .libPaths() just displayed the location of the library on my PC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks guys for the help. I did try `install.packages("caret", dep="TRUE")` which installed the package `digest`, then tried `install.packages("ggplot")` which installed `ggplot` with the dependency `gtable` but still had some missing packages. Did finally manage to load `caret` without any problems after installing the missing packages as prompted.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some packages that `ggplot2` *imports* (e.g. `digest` and `gtable`)

You should probably use

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports", "Suggests"))
```

This should be the same as `dep = TRUE` but, when I use the character string above, I get all the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line to install `ggplot2`:

```
install.packages('ggplot2', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

Answer (score 0):

install packages required and their library under R3.2.3 as caret built in this version and it is worked for me.

Comment: install.packages("randomForest")
install.packages("lattice")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("caret")
library(lattice)
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)

Comment: Just edit your answer to accommodate the actual packages instead of adding them as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Unistall R and Rstudio. Make sure to delete all folders realated including the ones ion C:\Users<>\AppData\Local

Then re-install
Rtools
R
Rstudio

Open Rstudio and execute << Make sure this is your path)

new_lib_path <- "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.3/library"
if (!dir.exists(new_lib_path)) dir.create(new_lib_path)
.libPaths(new_lib_path)

Comment: The OP's issue can be solved without uninstalling R and RStudio, as outlined by the other answers to this question.